# Limiting interactions with ETCD without impacting Performance

Tags: scala, caching, redis, akka, etcd

I have been working on limiting the interactions with ETCD server for my scala-maven application.

To give you all an idea on why we use ETCD is because my application in its entire lifecycle for an user interaction, WRITES, UPDATES, DELETES, LOCKS the data in ETCD using numerous keys.
There are multiple keys (10000+) for multiple scenarios and now I have run into an issue where these interactions have become too much for ETCD to handle.

What can be a better way to limit the interactions so that when an user tries to perform a task on my application, it doesn't over-burden the ETCD with aforementioned interactions?

To start with, I have thought of the followings:

1. Rate Limiting my calls to ETCD
2. Using Redis (Con: This would introduce a hop and might hinder with performance)
3. Using Thread Dispatcher

EXPECTATION: Need a better alternative to implement this scenario.

Thanks